# AttributeError: (Class) object has no attribute '__name__' Creating ModelForms [Django & Python2.7]

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, modelform

This is my first time using Django and I am completely stuck at how to use ModelForms in my project. I have been able to follow the online tutorials this far but without ModelForms(to add data into a Postgresql database), I can't proceed onward. I am trying to simply make a form page that lets the users add a few inputs (2 datefields and 1 textfield) and by submitting that form, the data will be added to the database.

The error I have been getting is:
AttributeError: 'Hyuga_Requests' object has no attribute '**name**' [where Hyuga_Request is a class set in the models.py]

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Hyuga_Requests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    s_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    e_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    reason = models.TextField(max_length=500)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .forms import Hyuga_RequestForm

def create_req(request):
    form = Hyuga_RequestForm()
    context = {"form":form,}
    return render(request,"request_form/requestform.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Hyuga_Requests
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Hyuga_RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hyuga_Requests()
        fields = ['name','s_date','e_date','reason']
```

Please help this noobie...

Answer (score 3):

Don't instantiate the model in the class Meta inside the Hyuga_RequestForm class.

`model = Hyuga_Requests()` should be `model = Hyuga_Requests`

Comment: Thank you so much. I eventually got it to work because of your help!

Answer (score 2):

model = Hyuga_Requests() -> model = Hyuga_Requests

Answer (score 1):

The error come because you are calling the model on the form.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Hyuga_Requests
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Hyuga_RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hyuga_Requests
        fields = ['name','s_date','e_date','reason']
```

Note: i suggest to you use on the any class you define on python not use "_", you can check more about PEP8 and code styles here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thank you so much. I eventually got it to work because of your help!